# Run an MSBuild target only if project is actually built

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, build-process, msbuild-4.0

I have an MSBuild file that builds **/*.sln files (builds all .sln files that exist).

The build uses the *Build* target, so if no changes were made to input files, no project should be built again.

I would like to execute some custom target **only if** a project actually gets built again.

How can this be done?

Both **AfterBuild** and **AfterCompile** are always called, no matter if the compile/build actually takes place.

Comment: is that target in every project file, or is it in a seperat projet file that also belongs to the solution?

Comment: that seems somewhat harder.. also, do you want the target built when any other project was built, or when all projects were built, or ... ?

Comment: after each one. Basically i'd like to copy each build's output (only ones that are built) to a certain folder, so i am left with only artifacts that were actually built.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically you want the same behaviour as the `PostBuildEvent` for instance, so I looked up how `Microsoft.Common.Targets` does it (this file *always* provides a nice insight in to how msbuild is supposed to be used). Here's the solution:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RunPostBuildEvent>OnOutputUpdated</RunPostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Target Name="RunWhenBuild" AfterTargets="CoreBuild"       
        Condition="'$(_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile)'!='$(_AssemblyTimestampAfterCompile)'">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="RunWhenBuild!!"/>
</Target>
```

And this is what goes on: when there is a property named `RunPostBuildEvent` with a value of `OnOutputUpdated` the `CoreBuild` target's dependncies will eventually record the timestamp of the output file before and after the build. And if they are equal the output was not build. So all that is left is getting your target to run after `CoreBuild` and checking on these timestamps.

Comment: yes, it's the standard (required for C#) import near the end of every csproj file. Without it you cannot (easily) build C# applications

Comment: Is the targets import still relevant in the newest (as of 2018) csproj format? i.e. this is removed by default from the current csproj format, I imagine it can continue to be omitted when following this?

Comment: For those that find this and are using new csproj format, note [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/677), which means if you use `<PostBuildEvent>...</PostBuildEvent>` instead of the approach mentioned here, you will not be able to use `$(OutDir)` etc.